# Display a readonly field in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am new in ASP.NET Core and would like to ask about displaying a field in w a view. 
I have a

```
class Person { 
    public string Name {get; set;} 
    public string Nickname {get; set;} 
}
```

Typically, in the `EditPerson` View, I do

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="Nickname" class="form-control" />
```

to display the fields.

But in my `EditPerson` View I need to display `Name` as readonly, and `Nickname` as editable field.

The `Name` should not be in a *textbox*(even readonly), but rather in a *label* or *div*...

Is there a standard approach to display such fields?

I don't want that the field to be updated back to the model or DB, I need only reading the field.

Comment: Just do: `<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly >` and take a look to https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/136269

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Output it as HTML with Razor syntax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor

```
@Model.Name
<input asp-for="Nickname" class="form-control" />
```

Note - this will need styling appropriately, or wrapping in `<span>` tag etc...

Comment: I am afraid the label will display the DisplayName of the field, not the field value, isn't it?

Comment: That should be `@Model.Name`

Answer (score 32):

Try this.

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="@(true)">
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="@(false)">
```

This render:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="Tom" readonly="readonly">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" value="Tom">
```

I realized it from here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7333#issuecomment-363504164

Comment: good point, but read the OP *The Name should not be in a textbox(even readonly)*

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true"/>
<input asp-for="Nickname" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: This will display the value in a textbox. The OP states `The Name should not be in a textbox`

Comment: also I don't want the field be updated back to the model

Comment: The field will not be updated,it would just make the textbox readonly

Comment: The second one won't generate the value of the property but a label for it (property name or DisplayName if specified). P.S: Regarding the first one - in addition if you manually forge the value of the input (and eventually remove the readonly attribute) the model will be updated so it's kinda not safe if you haven't validated it specifically on the server-side.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov more than that, label is readonly by default :)

Comment: @SamuilPetrov agreed

Answer (score 3):

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Add a ReadOnly attribute. Remember to include `using System.Component;` at the top of your class.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with how the markup is rendered.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the model property `Name` and don't want it to be an `input` element, just do this:

```
<p>@Model.Name</p>
```

**Important:** if you have used the `DisplayFormat` attribute on `Name` in your model (e.g. to apply number/date formatting or to control how blanks/nulls are displayed), you must do this instead:

```
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</p>
```

---

Of course, it doesn't need to be a `p`. Use a `div`, `span`, etc.

Give it a class and style it with CSS as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<input asp-for="Name" readonly="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))" />
<input asp-for="Nickname" />
```

Using any custom condition here, just make it return `true` or `false`. `readonly="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label class="form-control">@Model.Name</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
```